# How to set homemade c# web browser as default browser?

Tags: c#, registry, browser, default

I have made a web browser in c# and would like to set it as the default web browser.
What are the registry keys for this, and how to do it ?
Does it differ from WinXP, WinVista, and Win7 ? I use Windows 7.

Edit: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I would like to do that in application.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Which registry keys need to be edited to change the default browser?](http://superuser.com/questions/287313/which-registry-keys-need-to-be-edited-to-change-the-default-browser)

Comment: @MyCodeSucks I have came over that while googling, tried to set it using two different methods and didn't work well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows 7 you can set default program via Control Panel. It should be similar for all versions of Windows you mentioned.

```
Control Panel >> Programs >> Default Programs
```

or

```
Start >> Run >> Default Programs
```

**EDIT**
Thanks for editing. I am unsure on that but you would need something similar to [this](http://mel-green.com/2009/04/c-set-file-type-association/) I would assume. ([Once you get your Keys down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134253/how-to-set-default-program))

Comment: I want to set it programatically.

Comment: This has added my program to the list of programs I can open html files with, but how can I set the protocol http:// protocol to be default ?

Comment: @user1779764 Are you still trying to do that programmatically? you can get to the control panel and bind your pgram to deal with .html extensions by default. Sorry not sure how to do any of that in code, I answered before you edited your question.